# Ember Data createRecord Error on switching routes

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm getting the following error on createRecord

`` Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: You may not pass `null` as id to the store's find method ``

Create record is called here

```
var newSchool = this.store.createRecord('deal', {
      name: newSchoolName,
      timeZone: newTimeZone,
      locale: newLanguage,
      gradeNames: newGradeNames,
      standardSourceIds: newStandardSources,
      contentSourceIds: newContentSources,
      adminUserId: '511a48a7781200b2cd000001',
      numOfToken: 1,
      higherEd: higherEd,
      dealType: 'institution',
      parentDeal: this.get('model.deal')
    });
```

The problem is with the parentDeal it's a belongTo relationship if I change it to null there's no error.

Also the error is only thrown on switching routes and if I log this.get('model.deal') before hand it shows the object.

The model is declared in the route

```
model: function() {
return Ember.RSVP.hash({
  deal: this.store.find('deal', this.get('session.dealId')),
  contentSources: this.store.find('contentSource'),
  standardSources: this.store.find('standardSource')
});
},
```

Edit: After kitlers comments

I added the following to deactivate

```
deactivate: function() {
var model = this.get('model.deal');
if(model && model.get('isDirty')){
    model.get('transaction').save()
}

}
```

Also before hand this is what the store looked like in ember inspector

[image]

Comment: You either need to save the model or rollback on deactivation

Comment: @Kitler sorry but new to the framework do you mean the deal model that's declared in the route?

Comment: When you create a record it doesn't save until you call `.save()` on it, once that is done it persists the record to your db and marks it as `isDirty = false;` If you haven't saved it yet the `deal` record has no ID as it has not been persisted to the backend.

Comment: @Kitler I added that to deactivate, also I put a screenshot of what the store looked like before hand all the ones there are created successfuly without switching routes, the save call is called after the newSchool.createRecord, when theres an error it doesn't enter the error function on save()

Comment: The top record is the one being referenced in this.get('model.deal')

Comment: Ah wait I misread the question, missed the belongsTo part